# Safe & performant way to modify dask dataframe

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

As a part of data workflow I need to modify values in a subset of dask dataframe columns and pass the results for further computation. In particular, I'm interested in 2 cases: mapping columns and mapping partitions. What is the recommended safe & performant way to act on the data? I'm running it a **distributed setup on a cluster with multiple worker processes on each host**.

**Case1.**

I want to run:

```
res = dataframe.column.map(func, ...)
```

this returns a data series so I assume that original dataframe is not modified. Is it safe to assign a column back to the dataframe e.g. `dataframe['column']=res`? Probably not. Should I make a copy with *.copy()* and then assign result to it like:

```
dataframe2 = dataframe.copy()
dataframe2['column'] = dataframe.column.map(func, ...)
```

Any other recommended way to do it?

**Case2**

I need to map partitions of the dataframe:

```
df.map_partitions(mapping_func, meta=df)
```

Inside the *mapping_func()* I want to modify values in chosen columns, either by using `partition[column].map` or simply by creating a list comprehension. Again, how do modify the partition safely and return it from the mapping function?

Partition received by mapping function is a Pandas dataframe (copy of original data?) but while modifying data in-place I'm seeing some crashes (no exception/error messages though). Same goes for calling `partition.copy(deep=False)`, it doesn't work. Should partition be deep copied and then modified in-place? Or should I always construct a new dataframe out of new/mapped column data and original/unmodified series/columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can safely modify a dask.dataframe

Operations like the following are supported and safe

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(func)
```

This modifies the task graph in place but does not modify the data in place (assuming that the function `func` creates a new series).

#### You can not safely modify a partition

Your second case when you `map_partitions` a function that modifies a pandas dataframe in place is not safe.  Dask expects to be able to reuse data, call functions twice if necessary, etc..  If you have such a function then you should create a copy of the Pandas dataframe first within that function.

Comment: Is this still true? If yes, what is the suggested best practice of doing mutations, which if done using pandas could have been performed in-place, **without** doubling the memory consumption per-partition?